# What happens if I do not support arm64 in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, object, arm64

If I remove arm64 architecture from the build settings of Xcode and retain only armv7  and arm7s in my app what will happen?

1. What are the issues which may occur?
2. Will my app work on all iOS devices?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?"

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, why an earth would you not want to support arm64? If you don't then the app will run slower on 64-bit devices like the iPhone 6.

Comment: It may not  run at all on some future device. Apple hints like this.

Comment: in earth there many company have their sdk that still not support arm64 , i have to integrate that sdk  to our app so asked this question

Answer (score 4):

Your app **should** continue to work. However as of June 1 2015, all of the app uploads to the Apple App Store must contain the arm64 slice.

Comment: Do you have a citation for that? I can only find information saying that you `must include 64-bit support`, but that doesn't mean that you have to include `arm64`.
`x86_64` is also a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: The App Store upload process would look for it to be an `arm64` slice and won't be fooled with `x86_64`. Unless you're talking about macOS apps, at which point `x86_64` could be sufficient, for now.

Answer (score 1):

As Apple wrote in a [recent news post](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a):

> ### 64-bit and iOS 8 Requirements for New Apps
>
> **October 20, 2014**
>
> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to submit your app to the store. Apple is pushing forward x64 architectures.