# App size is big when compiling with arm7, arm7s & arm64 architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, arm

When I compile my application in Xcode with Valid architectures arm7, arm7s & arm64, the .ipa file is big (10 MB), when I compile it for arm7 binary is small(5.8 MB). Can I compile binary for arm7 yet support all latest iPhone devices and iOS versions.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if i not support arm64 in my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164691/what-happens-if-i-not-support-arm64-in-my-app)

Comment: check out the WWDC 2015... have you heared of "App thinning"?

Comment: ^ He still won't be able to ship anything using app thinning until September or so when iOS 9 comes out.

Comment: @AdamPro13 good point, I updated my answer. still, I suggest to just ignore the problem for the next two months. It will solve itself eventually.

Answer (score 2):

From [developer.apple.com page on App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html):

> The App Store and operating system optimize the installation of iOS
>   and watchOS apps by tailoring app delivery to the capabilities of the
>   user’s particular device, with minimal footprint. This optimization,
>   called app thinning, lets you create apps that use the most device
>   features, occupy minimum disk space, and accommodate future updates
>   that can be applied by Apple. Faster downloads and more space for
>   other apps and content provides a better user experience.

[...]

> Slicing is the process of creating and delivering variants of the app
>   bundle for different target devices. A variant contains only the
>   executable architecture and resources that are needed for the target
>   device. You continue to develop and upload full versions of your app
>   to iTunes Connect. The App Store will create and deliver different
>   variants based on the devices your app supports. Image resources are
>   sliced according to their resolution and device family. GPU resources
>   are sliced according to device capabilities. When the user installs an
>   app, a variant for the user’s device is downloaded and installed.

This means (among other things) that when the app is installed via the app store, only the architecture that is valid for a particular user, will be included in his download. Only during development and testing you will have to deal with big app sizes.

This feature was introduced during the WWDC 2015, so this is no longer an issue.